# Get-AzurePublishSettingFile : The term 'Get-AzurePublishSettingFile' is not recognized

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-cmdlet, azureshell

I have tried installing the Azure and AZ cmdlet via the command with AllowClobber and that successfully installed. I am running PowerShell as administrator and have connected my Azure account by signing in. However, when running the command "Get-AzurePublishSettingFile" the following error appears:

```
Get-AzurePublishSettingFile : The term 'Get-AzurePublishSettingFile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
```

included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- Get-AzurePublishSettingFile
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzurePublishSettingFile:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the ASM PowerShell module [`Azure`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure/5.3.1), and I notice you missed an `s` in your command, it should be `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile`, not `Get-AzurePublishSettingFile`.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure.service/get-azurepublishsettingsfile?view=azuresmps-4.0.0

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the answer. I should have marked this as solved earlier haha as I realised I had forgotten the "s" like an idiot. I spent so long browsing the web lol. Anyway thanks a lot. This question here will hopefully be a good reference to anyone that doesn't realise it should he "settings" instead of "setting"